# header Location no respeta el path que se declara

Tags: php

Estoy intentando matar una sesión si alguno de los índices de la global `$_SESSION` está vacío y redireccionarlo una página que destruye la sesión y re redirige al index. Tengo una estructura de este tipo en el árbol de archivos

```
backend
  apis
    profiles
      search.php
  core
    session_end.php
    CoreTools.php
frontend
index.php
landing.php
```

Este es mi código de `CoreTools.php`

```
class CoreTools{

  protected $session;
  public function __construct( $inSession ){
      $this->session = $inSession;
  }


  public function sessionLost(){

    $return = false;
    if( empty( $this->session ) ){
      $return = true;

    }else{
      foreach( $this->session as $s ){
          if( empty( $s ) ){$return = true;}
      }
    }


    return $return;
  }

  public function checkPermissions( $perm ){
    if( self::sessionLost() ){
      //He probado así
      $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/backend/core/session_end.php';
      header('Location: ' . $path );
      //También así
      echo '<script>window.location.href="./backend/core/session_end.php"</script>';
      //He probado de esta forma
      header('Location: http://www.misitio.com/backend/core/session_end.php');
     //Y de esta forma
     header('Location: session_end.php');

    }else{
      //Mucho code
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Esto lo invoco desde el archivo search.php

```
session_start();
require '../../core/CoreTools.php';
$_SESSION = null;
$tools = new CoreTools( $_SESSION );
if( !$tools->checkPermissions( 'get' ) ){
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'No tienes autorizado ver esta sección';

  }else{


  }
```

Estoy poniendo la `$_SESSION = null` de forma intencional para probar que funcione el header

El problema es que me dice un error 404

El primer intento con

```
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/backend/core/session_end.php';
header('Location: ' . $path);
```

me da esto

> Not Found The requested URL
>   /backend/apis/profiles/http//www.misitio.com/backend/core/session_end.php
>   was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Está buscando dentro de la carpeta de donde se invocó `( search.php )` pero dentro del path que armé.

El segundo intento con

```
header('Location: session_end.php');
```

Me da

> Not Found The requested URL /backend/apis/profiles/session_end.php was
>   not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

De igual forma como si estuviera intentando buscar el archivo de sesion_end.php dentro de profiles ( siendo que la instrucción está dentro del archivo `CoreTools.php` y este si está al nivel de `session_end.php`)

El echo del script de Javascript no funciona y la forma

```
header('Location: http://www.misitio.com/backend/core/session_end.php');
```

Me da un error de CORS ( Y no tengo planeado configurarlo )

No sé por qué no me está respetando la ruta de dónde está escrito el código y está tomando del que lo está invocando.

Espero me puedan apoyar

Comment: Prueba a ponerle / antes. header('Location: /session_end.php');

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar u_u

Comment: Prueba pasándole la ruta absoluta primeramente... ¿Depuraste las variables  ... por ejemplo qué imprimiría `echo $path;`  ... si copias pegas su resultado en el navegador no da error 404?

Comment: Alberto revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1242033/5587982) y sus respuestas. Hay varias recomendaciones interesantes en varias de ellas.